# Removing data above the mean

Tags: dataset, mean, outliers, filter

I am working with a data set, for which to remove noisy data I take the average of the sample itself and cut anything above that average. What I'm trying to understand here is does this have a name like I don't think this is mean filtering - but it would be helpful to know what type of filtering process this is since I need to explain it in a paper as for why I did it. Or is this just outlier removal?

Comment: What do you do about data that is well below the average?

Comment: This procedure sounds extreme, and and I've never heard of anything like it. As 'learner' asks, do you know that your noise is only positive?

You might want to describe what you are trying to do with the data: your solution might involve a different method rather than throwing out a lot of data.

Comment: I'm keeping the data below the average. So this is GPS data and I have the error/accuracy of each data point, so I average the errors and remove those who have a error of say 1km because the average may be something like 20m. Or maybe there is a better way to filter for such outliers? (because we are talking about people who are walking I didn't think I should use something as advanced as a Kalman filter)

Comment: Then you aren't really filtering the data for values above the mean (which, I agree, would be very extreme) you are filtering the data for *accuracy*.

Comment: This sounds like a form of variance-based weighting of the data: eliminating the data whose error indicators are high effectively weights them with zeros and all the other data are weighted equally. When the procedure is looked at this way, it becomes evident that there are better ones in common use; under some standard assumptions, inverse-variance weighting is optimal.